# effect of padding on cross correlation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

To find displacement of a particle, I calculated the cross correlation between two instants (represented by two images with the same size). Then, I padded the  images with zeros to see if a translation will have an effect on the displacement.

Thus I found a difference in displacement vector( the difference can reach 1.5 pixel and the size of image is 56x56 pixels)

Is it normal to find a difference after padding?

N.B:  To pad the image, I used

```
new_image(end+1:56,end+1:56)=0;
```

**EDIT**

The difference can even be more for some cases (22 px)

Comment: A bit offtopic, but you might be interested in `padarray` (https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is weird. The cross-correlation is calculated by multiplying values in both matrices with eachother and taking the sum of these. Adding zeros should not result in a greater sum.

The problem in the code you've posted is that `end+1:56` should likely be `end+1:end+56`, since you pad it with 56 extra zeros below and to the right of the image this way.

Since your goal appears to be to get the cross-correlation of 2 matrices, I recommend you to look at the `xcorr2()` and `xcorr()` functions in Matlab. An explanation for `xcorr2()` and why zero padding should not have any influence (besides searching a larger image) can be found [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, I pad it to be a matrix of 56x56, so if I write end+56 it will overcome 56 px